# How do you measure absolute pixel count?

Tags: html, css

I've recently found that most of the measurements I thought I knew were actually different from what I thought they where due to browser specific defaults.  I assessed that all my knowledge of my visual inspections were relative...item A is 20px so I can see that Item B is 22px.  However because of browser hidden defaults...this method doesn't work too well.  How can I know what absolute pixel count is.

Currently, I just created a 20px by 20px ruler in a graphics editor with tick marks.

Attached here

[image]

Now I can move this around by using absolute positioning and measure things.  However is there something built into the development tools to do this.  I'm using Firefox 10 right now.

Thanks

Comment: Well it's just an image I uploaded...let me see if there is attachment button.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FBg8Q.png

Comment: Chrome's inspector tool shows the dimension of any element that you happen to hover over.

Comment: @Diodeous - there is no attachment button but it looks like image uploads get posted to imgur...

Comment: @Vinny...good to know...I'm in FF 10 though.

Comment: Sorry, imgur is actually blocked in my workplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome's inspector tool shows the dimension of any element that you happen to hover over. However, if you must remain loyal to Firefox, Firebug can show the exact dimensions of any element upon hover as well. When you open up Firebug, click "Layout" in the sidebar to the right. Then, when you hover over an element, the dimensions will appear within that box (no clicking necessary). Not exactly as intuitive as Chrome's inspector tool, but it works regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for a tool to easily measure heights and widths without messing around in Firebug?

I'd suggest this add-on for Firefox (also available for Chrome): [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

If this isn't what you're looking for, can you please clarify?

*Edit:* If you can't install software or add-ons, use the no-install [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/)

Comment: Well..I can't change my software...I only have access to basic FF 10 Debug tools...thought I was missing it somewhere...I have access to console only via Control Shift K

Comment: Use Firebug Lite then (assuming you can't install web developer or firebug): http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/

Comment: Chrome's built in tools are better than add on tools, FYI.

Comment: True, but I try to avoid browser wars, and thus do not suggest anyone to change their browser as a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 2):

- there is a sweet measurement tool called "measure it."  you can find it [HERE](http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/measureit-simple-ruler-extension-firefox/).  that's the best one i have found so far.
- another thought... you could check and make sure all of your different browsers aren't at all zoomed in... view actual size etc...
- also - are you using a "reset" of any kind ?  if not - you could check out the meyer reset - or normalize... or - the freak reset... (that combines both).

Comment: I would add that, these days, (2013) most of us are using ems because they are understood more clearly by more browsers as well as having many magical cascading bonuses.